# Laravel how to generate urls using GET route names?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I got this 2 routes in my routes file (web)

```
    Route::get('management/special-fees/add/{userId}', 'Management\SpecialFeeController@create')->name('management/special-fees/add');
    Route::post('management/special-fees/add', 'Management\SpecialFeeController@store')->name('management/special-fees/add');
```

They both share the same name but one is GET and the other is POST, so far so good. But now I want to make an url in my view to open the form, for that I use the method route() like this

```
route('management/special-fees/add',$user->id )
```

but when trying to go to the url I get this route

```
.../management/special-fees/add?5
```

there is a question mark instead of a "/" so the route is invalid.

I made some tests and I figured out that happens because is trying to go to the POST route instead of the GET one if I change the POST route's url in the web file like this

```
Route::get('management/special-fees/add/{userId}', 'Management\SpecialFeeController@create')->name('management/special-fees/add');
Route::post('management/special-fees/addSSSS', 'Management\SpecialFeeController@store')->name('management/special-fees/add');
```

I will in fact get this url

```
.../management/special-fees/addSSSS?5
```

So why is the route() method generating a url for the POST route over the GET one? how do I make it to choose the GET route first?

Comment: Instead of .../management/special-fees/add?5 use .../management/special-fees/add/5

Answer (score 0):

In laravel the routing is prioritized by in the order it is written in your `route.php` file.

In this case you're writing the `Route::post` last, which in turn tells Laravel that *that* one should have the highest priority. Try switching them and the `Route::get` will have the higher priority.

Like so:

```
Route::post('management/special-fees/addSSSS', 'Management\SpecialFeeController@store')->name('management/special-fees/add');
Route::get('management/special-fees/add/{userId}', 'Management\SpecialFeeController@create')->name('management/special-fees/add');
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I think you'll have to re-think route naming. One of the problems route naming helps eliminate is redundant and complex names. For example, if you looked at route:list for `Route::resource('something', 'SomethingController')` it will have `something.index`, `something.store` as route names for `Route::get('something')` and `Route::post('something')`.

If it's the same name, it will always resolve to the first one and will probably never hit the second route; in your case will hit the POST route and never the GET route.

Answer (score 0):

?5 means 5 is an argument for your get route.
try this

> url('management/special-fees/add/'.$user->id)

for get route insted of

> route('management/special-fees/add',$user->id )